# Why does printf and cout gives different output for this code?

Tags: c++, bit-shift

```
int main(){
    ll a=pow(2,32);
    cout <<a<<endl;
    cout << (-1<<1)<<endl;
    printf("%x",-1<<1);
}
```

For the above code, I am getting following output:

```
4294967296
-2
fffffffe
```

`4294967296` in decimal is equal to `fffffffe` in hexadecimal which is basically `2^32`. Why is printf and cout behaving differently? And how exactly does this shift works?

Comment: Try `printf("%d", ...)` instead.

Comment: 4294967296 is most certainly not equal to fffffffe. The former is `2^32`, the latter is `2^32-2`.

Comment: There is a difference of interpretation as to whether left shifting a negative number is *undefined* or not. John created a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19593938/is-left-shifting-a-negative-integer-undefined-behavior-in-c11) to see if we can resolve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `printf` format flag `%x` means to print an integral value in hexadecimal.

There is a stream manipulator to accomplish this as well (`std::hex`), but you're not using that. When you output an integral value to a stream with no manipulators, it outputs in base 10.

[See here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) for more information about the `printf` format flags, [and here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip) for information about stream manipulators.

The shift operator `<<` works as described in the C++03 Standard (14882:2003):

### 5.8 Shift operators

> 1/ The shift operators << and >> group left-to-right.
>       shift-expression:
>           additive-expression
>           shift-expression << additive-expression
>           shift-expression >> additive-expression
>
> The operands shall be of integral or enumeration type and integral
>   promotions are performed. The type of the result is that of the
>   promoted left operand. The behavior is undefined if the right operand
>   is negative, or greater than or equal to the length in bits of the
>   promoted left operand.
>
> 2/ The value of E1 << E2 is E1 (interpreted as a bit pattern)
>   left-shifted E2 bit positions; vacated bits are zero-filled. If E1 has
>   an unsigned type, the value of the result is E1 multiplied by the
>   quantity 2 raised to the power E2, reduced modulo ULONG_MAX+1 if E1
>   has type unsigned long, UINT_MAX+1 otherwise.
>
> [Note: the constants ULONG_MAX and UINT_MAX are defined in the header
>   ). ]

In your case, the value `-1` in binary is all `1`s in every bit.  For a 32 bit value, then:

```
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111
```

If you shift this left 1 bit using `<<`, you get:

```
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111110
```

Which in base 10 is -2.  Since the operation `-1<<1` uses a negative number for the LHS, the entire expression is of a signed (not unsigned) type.

Comment: But Why it is printing "-2" in case of cout? Shouldn't it print "4294967296"? I am asking how come the two values are different. I understand the difference between hexadecimal and decimal representation.

Comment: @JohnDibling You only need 32-bits to show `-1 << 1` as they are both `int`s and not `long long`s.

Comment: @ZacHowland:  I know, but the OP's code used `ll` as a type declaration for `a`, which I guessed meant `uint64_t`.

Comment: @JohnDibling For `a`, yes.  Everything he did after that was dealing with 32-bit `int`s though (which is a big part of his overall problem).

Comment: @ZacHowland:  I suppose you're right.  I made then 32 bit values.

Answer (score 1):

First,

> fffffffe in hexadecimal which is basically 2^32

is wrong.  FFFFFFFE = 4294967294, which is 2^32 - 2 (for unsigned integers), or -2 (for 32-bit signed integers in 2's complement).

Second, `printf("%x", ...)` will print an unsigned hexadecimal integer (that is an `unsigned int`), which is 32-bits on most modern systems.  `long long a = 2 << 32` requires a 64-bit integer to properly store it (or, more precisely, at least a 33-bit integer), so when you use `cout << a`, you are calling `ostream& operator<<(ostream&, long long)`, which has the proper type.  That is, you are running into an overflow issue because of the type used by the printf specifier vs the strong type used by the C++ `operator<<` overload.

Answer (score 1):

This code invokes [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) since you are trying to *left shift* a negative number, [the draft C++11 Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf)  section `5.8` *Shift operators* says(*emphasis mine*):

> The value of E1 << E2 is E1 left-shifted E2 bit positions; vacated
>   bits are zero-filled. If E1 has an unsigned type, the value of the
>   result is E1 × 2E2, reduced modulo one more than the maximum value
>   representable in the result type. Otherwise, if **E1 has a signed type
>   and non-negative value**, and E1×2E2 is representable in the result
>   type, then that is the resulting value; otherwise, **the behavior is
>   undefined**.

This is also the same for the [draft C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) section `6.5.7` *Bitwise shift operators*

It is also *undefined behavior* to specify an *invalid* conversion specifier to `printf`, you are specifying `%x` which expect an *unsigned int* but the result is *signed*. The *C99 draft* in section `7.19.6.1` *The fprintf function* paragraph *9* says:

> If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined.248) If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is
>   undefined.

Comment: `E1` here does not have non-negative value. Also, this does not match the Standard I wuoted (C++03)

Comment: @JohnDibling This is `n3485` so as far as I remember the language has changed from `03`. Right so the quote says `E1` is non-negative then it is defined as otherwise it is undefined which fits this case.

Comment: Edited your post to include the text from the published Standard, rather than the draft.  There are some differences.

Comment: So, are you interpreting this to mean that left-shifting a negative number results in Undefined Behavior?

Comment: Did you intentionally (effectively) roll back my edits and go back to the draft standard?

Comment: @JohnDibling I was in the middle of another edit and did not see your comment. Regardless I would be reluctant to quote what I don't have in front of me.

Comment: I did not vandalize your answer.

Comment: @JohnDibling Not suggesting you did, I know that your intentions were only to improve the answer.

Comment: @JohnDibling Also the latest draft C++ standard has very similar language, I usually pick them up from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents) thread and so I feel comfortable using this quote.

Comment: Back to an earlier question:  are you interpreting this to mean that left-shifting a negative number results in Undefined Behavior?

Comment: Also, take a look here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19593938/is-left-shifting-a-negative-integer-undefined-behavior-in-c11

Comment: @JohnDibling It sure reads to me that it is undefined but I am willing to be convinced otherwise. Let's see what answers your questions receives.

Comment: I can totally see how you would interpret it that way, but I interpreted it the other way.  Let's see what happens.

Comment: @JohnDibling So it seems like the consensus is that it is indeed *undefined*, doubt I will get the up vote back but at least I learned something interesting.

Comment: Well, I'll give you one instead.

Answer (score 0):

`%x` formats the output to show the value in hexadecimal, so you should pass `std::hex` to `cout` to do a same thing:

```
std::cout << std:::hex << (-1<<1) << endl;
             ^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

This will produce the correct same answer as you need to tell it to print in hex

```
cout << hex<<(-1<<1)<<endl;
printf("%x",-1<<1);
```

Answer (score 0):

%x is hex where as the cout are just outputting the numbers (int) directly
-1 is 0xFFFFFFFF shift that to the left you have to add in a 0 
ie so the last F (in binary is 1111 becomes 1110 ie E
The other guys answer your points clearer I think....

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of readbility let's use a signed 8bit integer:

```
-1 bitwise is 11111111
```

now doing a left-shift by 1:

```
-1 << 1
```

you get:

```
11111110 which is -2
```

However using the the conversion specifier `%x` tells `printf()` to tread `11111111` as **un**-signed so it prints out `fe`.

Answer (score 0):

The first case is valid: `pow(2,32)` returns the exact value 2<sup>32</sup> as a `double`, which remains exact when you convert it to `long long` (I'm assuming that's what the mystery `ll` type is). Printing this with `cout` is perfectly valid.

In the case of `(-1<<1)`, left-shifting a negative number yields undefined behavior. Even if the compiler does define it as -2 (most will), it's also undefined behavior to pass a negative number for use with `printf`'s `%x` specifier (which requires an unsigned type).