# Undefined behavior of constexpr static cast from int to unscoped enum with non-fixed underlying type compiles in C++17

Tags: c++, enums, c++17, undefined-behavior, constexpr

This is a follow up question of [Undefined behavior of constexpr static cast from int to scoped enum with non-fixed underlying type compiles in C++17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66664841/undefined-behavior-of-constexpr-static-cast-from-int-to-scoped-enum-with-non-fix) (same question for **scoped** enumerations).
TLDR is that scoped enums always have a fixed underlying type (by default int, hence you can always cast from int to scoped enum).

I wonder if the following should or should not compile in C++17

```
enum E
{
    A, B
};

constexpr E x = static_cast<E>(2);
```

This compiles with both GCC 9.3.0 and Clang 10.0.0 on Ubuntu 20.04.

My question is

1. Should this compile?
2. If it should, why?

See the other post for a detailed reasoning why I think it should not compile for **unscoped** enums. The same reasoning applies for this question as well.

Comment: Please explain why you vote down the question so that I can improve the question. The question is well defined and is not a duplicate of any other. I have done thorough research on the subject (as shown in the other thread), and I am trying to solve an underlying problem that would use the fact that the above code is ill-formed. I choose to not post all information in this question, since I don't want to copy paste too much from the other thread (if that is what you don't like, but what do I know?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should not compile. It's a compiler bug. The reason it was made undefined in [CWG 1766](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1766) was so that this conversion would be diagnosed in constant expressions.

This is [GCC bug #95701](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=95701). I could not find an open bug for Clang.

Comment: Thanks! I will make sure to check out the buglists before posting this kind of questions in the future.

Comment: They are great sources but not always the easiest to search. You're welcome.

Comment: Just for completeness in case people find themselves here, this is the bug report for LLVM: [#50055](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/50055).
It will be fixed in [Clang 16](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ReleaseNotes.html#potentially-breaking-changes).