# Why doesn't this swap macro using shifts not work for negative numbers?

Tags: c, macros, bit-shift

I found some code in a built in library that I have and need to extend.

But it appears to be broken:

```
#define BSWAP16(__x)    ((((__x) >> 8) | ((__x) << 8)))
```

Does not function the same as:

```
__builtin_bswap16()
```

This program proves it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define BSWAP16(__x)    ((((__x) >> 8) | ((__x) << 8)))

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    unsigned short a = (unsigned short)BSWAP16(0xff00);
    unsigned short b = __builtin_bswap16(0xff00);
    short c = (short)BSWAP16(-8);
    short d = __builtin_bswap16(-8);

    printf("a=%04x, b=%04x, c=%04x, d=%04x\n", a,b,c,d);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
a=00ff, b=00ff, c=ffffffff, d=fffff8ff
```

I'm not wanting answers telling me I should use endian.h or __builtin_bswap16.  On the target platform used by this in-house library on this platform/compiler configuration, I'm triggering this default code that is defaulting to using the above macro.

So my question is.  Why doesn't it work for negative numbers?

If I represent -8 as a short value of 0xfff8 it works.

So I'm guessing it has something to do with internal conversion to int.

How do I fix this macro to work properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is undefined behavior to left shift a negative number, from the draft C99 standard section `6.5.7` *Bitwise shift operators* which says (*emphasis mine going forward*):

> The result of E1 << E2 is E1 left-shifted E2 bit positions; vacated
>   bits are filled with zeros. If E1 has an unsigned type, the value of
>   the result is E1 ´ 2E2, reduced modulo one more than the maximum value
>   representable in the result type. **If E1 has a signed type and
>   nonnegative value**, and E1 ´ 2E2 is representable in the result type,
>   then that is the resulting value; **otherwise, the behavior is
>   undefined.**

So the result of the left shift of `-8` is unpredictable. Casting to *unsigned short* should fix the issue:

```
BSWAP16((unsigned short)-8)
```

`-8` is an integer constant(*literal*) and since it does not have a suffix will be an *int* since *int* can take on it's value. Assuming `32-bit` *int* and twos complement will have have the following value:

```
 FFFFFFF8
```

casting to *unsigned short* will remove the unwanted higher bits. Casting to *unsigned int* won't help since it will preserve the higher bits.

Also right shifting a negative number is implementation defined:

> The result of E1 >> E2 is E1 right-shifted E2 bit positions. If E1 has
>   an unsigned type or if E1 has a signed type and a nonnegative value,
>   the value of the result is the integral part of the quotient of E1 /
>   2E2. **If E1 has a signed type and a negative value, the resulting value
>   is implementation-defined.**

Comment: @MattMcNabb not correct, `clang` provides the following error for the  code `runtime error: left shift of negative value -8` when using `-fsanitize=undefined `

Comment: ahh, thanks for that.  I'm not actually bit shifting negative numbers at all.  This all came about because I was being forced to cast and then wondered what would happen with negative values.  Thanks for the feedback.  I can avoid the cast with a bitmask.

Comment: @R.. as far as I can tell the wording is the same as C++11 and the consensus [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19593938/is-left-shifting-a-negative-integer-undefined-behavior-in-c11) was that it was indeed undefined and Howard Hinnant confirmed this to be so but also said post C++11 the wording was tweaked. Also I specifically cited C99 although I don't think the wording has changed.

Answer (score 2):

You should mask out the unwanted bits before shifting.

```
#define BSWAP16(__x)    (((((__x) & 0xFF00) >> 8) | (((__x) & 0xFF) << 8)))
```

Regarding why it doesn't work without shifting, note that `-8` is indeed `0xFFFFFFF8`. Without masking, there are plenty of higher `1` bits. `int` is used during computation.

Comment: You know I had just figured out that masking seems to fix it although I masked it with 0xffff in both cases.  Can you explain why the masking is necessary and why casting to (short) the result doesn't work?

Comment: This still causes undefined behaviour if `int` is 16-bit; to get defined behaviour, convert the value to `unsigned int` before shifting.

Comment: @Matt the C standard does not define shifting `1`'s in or out of the sign bit (to put it informally). Masking fixes this (i'm assuming you're using 32-bit ints or larger) because after that mask is applied then only zeroes go through the sign bit.

Comment: @MattMcNabb, casting to unsigned int doesn't work. But casting to unsigned short does.  #define BSWAP16((((unsigned short)(__x)) >> 8) | (((unsigned short)(__x)) << 8))

Comment: @Matt that version doesn't work for values greater than 255 , unless you also truncate to 16 bits afterwards