# Unexpected behavior while dealing with shift operators

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

My program is written below:

```
void main() {
   int n =0;
   printf("%x", (~0 << (32+ (~n +1) )));
}
```

As n = 0, ~n = 0xffffffff == -1, so ~n + 1 is equal to 0. 
When I execute this program, I get 0xffffffff, which is incorrect as (~0 << 32 ) outputs 0.

When I replace (~n +1) with 0, it outputs 0.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11270492/what-does-the-c-standard-say-about-bitshifting-more-bits-than-the-width-of-type

Comment: @mafso: I don't see how? _[edit: okay, that question should say "greater than or equal to", but it's still not a duplicate]_

Comment: Also, you should use `int main()` instead of `void main()`

Comment: Using `%x` to output an `int` also causes undefined behaviour. Use `%d`, or make the thing you're outputting be an `unsigned int`.

Comment: Also related to [Why doesn't this swap macro using shifts not work for negative numbers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24565837/why-doesnt-this-swap-macro-using-shifts-not-work-for-negative-numbers)

Answer (score 6):

You're shifting a 32-bit wide value by 32 bits.
The result is undefined and could equal mushroom lasagna for all you know.

> `[C99: 6.5.7/3]:` The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands. The type of the result is that of the promoted left operand. **If the value of the right operand** is negative or **is greater than or equal to the width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is undefined.**

Any further analysis, then, is folly.

Comment: Thanks! I read that clause, but I don't get why the behavior is consistent in both cases.

Comment: @KumarVikramjeet: You mean inconsistent? IIRC, on x86, only the 5 lowest bits of the right operand are used for shifts with 32 bit types. If you write a literal 0, e.g. Gcc evaluates the expression at compile time (with a different result). The same happens when I compile your code with `gcc -O1` (Gcc can infer that `~n+1` is 0).

Comment: @KumarVikramjeet: Because of the last line in my answer.

Comment: @Mafso I meant why the behavior was consistent in both cases separately. Never mind, I got what u said, thanks!

Comment: Note that left-shifting `~0` by *any* number of bits (except `0`) causes undefined behaviour.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Why's that? Cos no unsigned representation?

Comment: @LightnessRacesInOrbit `~0` is negative, and left-shifting negative values causes UB (6.5.7/4). Actually shifting by `0` bits is also UB, there's no exception stated for that case.